# Parse error in .Rmd

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to knit an .Rmd and I keep getting

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:1:1: unexpected '$'
```

The line that is generating this error message is:

```
$\frac{51}{60}$
```

Any idea why I'm getting this message? I've tried all variations of `$` and `/` in the equation, and even copied and pasted a different fraction example I found online and still get that message

Answer (score 2):

You're probably putting that line inside a chunk:

````
```{r}
# don't put me here!
```
````

Put it in the main body of the document instead.